# How do I load the file I need? PHP

Tags: php, phpunit, bootstrapping

While this might be a basic question, one would assume use `require_once`, its actually more complicated then that - at least for me.

The issue I am having is that I have a project structure much like a package structure in Java. How ever we use a global name space. So the project Structure looks something like:

```
ProjectName/
  ModuleOne/
    Class.php
    composer.json
    tests/
      phpunit.xml
      bootstrap.php
      Class_test.php
```

In the above example `Class.php` would be instantiated as such: `ProjectName\ModuleOne\Class();`

Now the issue is how we set up our tests directory, because `Class_test.php` will use `Class.php` and any other classes that one depends on, I need some way to allow me to instantiate in my test, the class in question. When ever I attempt to I get an error saying it cant find the class in question that I am trying to instantiate.

While this might be an unusual way of doing things, the project is such that each module can be exported out using composer and auto loaded into your project using the namespace we have chosen, in this case `ProjectName`.

The issue I seem to be having is that I need each class outside the `tests/` directory to be auto loaded and ready to go, such that if `Class.php` extends any other class then when `Class.php` is called it will know, "ok I need to go here to see if this other class exists as well."

Now each Module does have a composer file and inside we do have something like:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "ProjectName\\ModuleOne\\": ""
    }
  },
```

So could I use this some how in the bootstrap.php to auto load this whole module for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you include the autoload.php file composer creates in your bootstrap.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel and I would go with the package structure suggested by composer.

A quick google search gave me the link to this blog post: [How to create a PSR-4 PHP package](http://culttt.com/2014/05/07/create-psr-4-php-package/). It pretty much describes, how the file structure of a composer package should look like and how to set up and organize the tests of your package.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Assuming you have the structure suggested in the post above, all you need to do is to tell phpunit where to find the autoload file created by composer. If you need a more complex bootstrapping, you can do following. Create a file `tests/bootstrap.php` and add following content to it:

```
require_once 'path/to/composer/autoload.php';
// Set up your stubs, mocks etc.
```

In your phpunit.xml file you need to point the phpunit to the correct bootstrap file, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Nacho Test Suite">
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Alternatively you can run phpunit with `--bootstrap` flag, e.g.:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap path/to/bootstrap.php
```

Comment: Thats actually how I am doing things, because I stole my setup from Zend Framework. So I am sticking with convention. I just didn't show you all of my composer.json file.

So how would you use the composer.json in relation with phpunit to load this module?

Comment: If your classes are correctly autoloaded by composer and if you don't need any additional bootstrapping for your tests, add `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` to your phpunit.xml config (as suggested in the link above). I will edit the answer to show give you an example with additional bootstrapping.